# Why do not electrostatics transform into electrodynamics?

Tags: electrostatics

I was studying some computational techniques to simulate electrostatics and electrodynamics and a question came to my mind. Imagine a simple system of two parallel grounded electrodes at $V = 0$. Imagine a uniform charge distribution $\rho_0$ created by a number $n_e$ of electrons. This is a typical electrostatic configuration. However, electrons interact one with each other by the Coulomb force. Why can we affirm that the electrons do not move and that such an electrostatic system does exist?

Comment: I think in such a system you fix the position of the charge, hence electrostatics. Another question would be whether such a system is stable, i.e. if you did not limit the motion of charges, would they stay where they are, but this is not quite electrostatics question, though you could frame it as such by seeking configurations with minimum energy

Comment: Can I think of it like a charged rubber ball due to friction? The charges are on the surface and for a long time they "don't move", but if you wait long enough, they disappear because of interactions with themselves and the sorroundings. Therefore, the system of my question might be stable "for a short enough time".

Comment: Sure. In essence, you compose your equations of motion, and then throw out all terms that are too small, so for example the rate of change in charge density $d\rho/dt$ could be small if the scale of time on which this happens is too long, then you could throw it out. Charged rubber ball with fixed net charge in presence of two grounded electrodes seems like a typical electrostatics setting. One thing I did not mention is the *existence of solutions* as a mathematical question. These things are usually proven in advanced texts, but you will need to settle on which equations to solve first

Comment: Note that you can solve only for fields/potentials with given fixed charge densities, and boundary conditions, or you could solve for fields and charges given boundary conditions, and perhaps some integral conditions (e.g. net charge is fixed). In the latter case one can use Gauss laws to re-express charge density in terms of divergence of electric field.